# Layout weights are not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]I'm trying to display 3 sections in an activity - one fixed to the top(header), the other one is scrollview and the last one is fixed to the bottom.
I'm using `weightSum` and `layout_weight` but for some reasons it's not working.

I need the portions to be: 2:7:1

*Im trying to get the view as described in the picture, instead im getting display as the second picture*[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroud"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UNITS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit1Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="423 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="358"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit1Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit1Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit2Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 2"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="336 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="298"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit2Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit2Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your Scrollview have 0dp as it's `layout_height`?

Comment: Can you describe the issue more specifically? How exactly it is not working? Perhaps including a screenshot would help

Comment: make 0dp height and add this `android:fillViewport="true"` to scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Use **`android:layout_height="0dp"`** amd **`android:fillViewport="true"`** to your **`ScrollView`**

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/goku"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UNITS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit1Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="423 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="358"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit1Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit1Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit2Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 2"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="336 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="298"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit2Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit2Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: What should I use for my scroll view and grid layout so I can add more cards (10) and give to each card fixed size (all the same)?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with you ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroud"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UNITS"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/unit1Card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/unit1Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Unit 1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="423 Words"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Green"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="358"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Yellow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="32"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit1Red"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit1Green"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Red"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="8"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/unit2Card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/unit2Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Unit 2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="336 Words"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Green"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="298"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Yellow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="32"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit2Red"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit2Green"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Red"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="8"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And you'll be good to go!! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna implement weights,your `layout_width` should be `0dp`.try it,height let it be `match_parent` or `wrap_content`,but keep your width `0dp`,
(if thats horizontal in view),and than use `layout_weight` as per your requirement,same as in vertical case,if you wanna assign weights vertically,keep height as `0dp` as `1` or `2` or whatever as per your requirement. if this is not your answer,than just ignore this answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


 android:background="@drawable/backgroud"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="UNITS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit1Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit1Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="423 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="358"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit1Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit1Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/unit2Card"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/unit2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Unit 2"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit1Words"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="336 Words"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Green"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="298"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Yellow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="32"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/unit2Red"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/unit2Green"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/unit2Red"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="8"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```